# Is there a way my XAML resource can inherit from another XAML resource?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="helpDetail" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#555555" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="HelpGrid0" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#555555" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="HelpGrid1" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#555555" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
</Style>
```

Is there a way that I can eliminate the need to specify FontSize in the 2nd two resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use style inheritance. Use the `BasedOn` attribute and specify the name of the style you want to base your second style on. You will then just have to specify the properties that are different from the first style.

I.e.:

```
<Style x:Key="HelpGrid0" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource helpDetail}">
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/inheritance